# How To Hide New Document from Ribbon Classic SharePoint online?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, ribbon-control

How to hide New Document menu from classic SharePoint Online Ribbon UI?

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Ojq.png)

I am already using Toolbar Type with "No Toolbar".

But I want to hide "New Document", "Upload Document", and "New Folder" button from Ribbon.

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use browser debugger tools where you can find classes/id's for these controls and containers. Then using some JavaScript code or CSS in a script editor webpart, you can use hide these controls.
However, Generally, you can define appropriate permissions for users for whom you want to disable these controls.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS style into a script editor web part in list view page.

```
<style>
li[id='Ribbon.Documents.New']{
    display:none !important;
}
span[id='Ribbon.Documents.EditCheckout-LargeMedium-0']{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]